# Wrong output from Caret's specificity function

Tags: r

I was using this specificity of Caret but it does not give correct result. I calculates the recall instead I think. Did anyone encounter this question ever?

```
truth = c(1,1,0)
pred = c(1,0,1)
specificity(as.factor(pred), as.factor(truth), positive="1") # output is 0.5 but it should be 0
sensitivity(as.factor(pred), as.factor(truth), positive="1") # 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The result for the first line of specificity should be 0.5 indeed - you have 1 right positive on the first observation (the predicted and real value are equal).